# updating horizontal ProgressDialog using Handler, while loading an image from the web

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Is it possible to update the horizontal (determinate) ProgressDialog using Handler (I deliberately don't want to use AsyncTask), while loading an image from the web? and if so, how do I do that?

this is the try block:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
if(httpCon.getResponseCode()!=200) return;
InputStream inputStream = httpCon.getInputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can pass data via `Message` class and get them in `handleMessage(Message msg)` method of `Handler` for example this way (`msg.arg1` - downloaded bytes, `msg.arg2` - total bytes to download):

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image ...");
progressDialog.setMessage("Download in progress ...");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setProgress(0);
progressDialog.setMax(100);
progressDialog.show();

final Handler downloadProgressHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(100 * msg.arg1 / msg.arg2);
        if (progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
};

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("<your_url>");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            ByteArrayOutputStream receivedBytesStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int downloadedSize = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                receivedBytesStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.arg1 = downloadedSize;
                msg.arg2 = totalSize;
                downloadProgressHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            receivedBytesStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}).start();
```

Or if You don't want to sent data via `msg.arg1` and `msg.arg2` You can create custom object and add it to message like that `msg.obj = new YourCustomObjectClass() // or any other object`. And You can get it in `handleMessage(Message msg)` method like this: `YourCustomObjectClass obj = (YourCustomObjectClass) msg.obj;`

Comment: thank you Andriy!

fyi, `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);` and `urlConnection.connect();` crashed the app, so I removed them. I also removed `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");` because `HttpURLConnection` uses the `GET` method by default... 
anyway it workes now :)

Comment: You welcome! And You are right: `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly decoding the InputStream  to Bitmap, Download the file to any path in your device. And from the onProgressUpdate method of the asynchtask, you can update the progress.  After the file is download open the file and set to imageview.

Eg with Asynchtask

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        // setting downloaded into image view
        my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

}
```

You can call this with

```
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(link);
```

Comment: I was trying to do that without AsyncTask, but thanks anyway!